# iPhone Simulator starts wrong project

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I have an old iPhone application that copied to a new location in order to reuse it.

So I
- copied the project directory to a new folder
- created a new xCode project and linked all copied files to edit
- edited the frameworks and plist files to point to the new project name.

The project compiles and can be run, but when I click "Build & run" in xCode, xCode builds the new project and executes the original project.

Am running xCode3.2 with iOS4.2

Any ideas ???
cheers

Answer (score 0):

When Xcode requests that the simulator launch something, it seems to do it by product name only. Something that has happened to me more than once is that I've changed the bundle identifier on my project, subsequent builds have led to two products with the same product name on the device, then I've become a bit confused when changes I'm making don't seem to take effect.

Solutions are either to delete the older product from the simulator (which works the same as on a real device; tap and hold) or to change your product name. I have to admit that I've not tested changing the product name and the bundle display name so that the app has the same visible name on the device but a different .app name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Product Name was the first avenue I went after, but since I created a new product anyway, the name is unique (different to the tmplate's name).

Comment: In that case I've never seen the behaviour you describe and can't otherwise think of a reason for it. Sorry I can't be more helpful.